# How to gracefully process method arguments after I changed their number and types?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use `save_form_data` method with a *new signature*. But currently my server has a lot of jobs in its queue that depends on *old signature* - server knew that method took 2 parameters, but *new signature* takes only a single argument.

```
# new signature
# params: Hash
def save_form_data(params)
  process(params['catcher_token'], params['form_data'])
end

# old signature
# catcher_token: String, form_data: Array
def save_form_data(catcher_token, form_data)
  process(catcher_token, form_data)
end
```

I think I need to change *new signature* method with a version that **must** accept 2 parameters as it did before. Then inside it I can check if `params` is of type `Hash` and if it is - just ignore `foobar`. But it solves only half of a problem because new calls of type: `save_form_data(params)` now will fail (I think) because method accepts 2 arguments, not 1...

```
# modified new signature method
def save_form_data(params, foobar)
  if params.class == Hash
    process(params['catcher_token'], params['form_data'])
  else
    process(params, foobar)      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. You need to make a compatible signature. And distinguish between the old and new format inside of the method. After a while, you'll be able to delete this compat layer (when all old jobs are done).

Also, don't use concrete class checks. Do "is a" checks.

```
if params.is_a?(Hash)
```

This code will work for subclasses of hash too (like `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, for example), whereas your code will not.

Comment: But my modified new signature solves only half of a problem because new calls of type: `save_form_data(params)` will fail (I think) because method accepts 2 arguments, not 1...

Comment: @yaru: this one is easy - have a default value for the second parameter. `def save_form_data(params, foobar = nil)`

Answer (score 3):

Just set a default value for the second parameter:

```
def save_form_data(params, foobar = nil)
  case params
  when Hash
    process(params['catcher_token'], params['form_data'])
  else
    process(params, foobar)      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `*args` and a `case` statement to explicitly handle different number of arguments. Something like this:

```
def save_form_data(*args)
  case args.size
  when 1
    process(args[0]['catcher_token'], args[0]['form_data'])
  when 2
    process(args[0], args[1])
  else
    raise ArgumentError, "wrong number of arguments (#{args.size} for 1..2)"
  end
end
```

You could also add a deprecation warning:

```
when 2
  ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(<<-MSG.squish)
    Passing `catcher_token` and `form_data` separately to `save_form_data` is
    deprecated, please pass the `params` Hash instead.
  MSG
  process(args[0], args[1])
```

Or input validation:

```
when 1
  raise TypeError, "expected Hash, got #{args[0].class}" unless args[0].is_a?(Hash)
```